# What on earth is pv -bartpes

Tags: pv

Many pages advise using a switch for `pv` called `-bartpes`. The following command from [this page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Securely_wipe_disk/Tips_and_tricks) is an example:

```
# openssl enc -aes-256-ctr -pass pass:"$(dd if=/dev/urandom bs=128 count=1 2>/dev/null | base64)" -nosalt </dev/zero \
| pv -bartpes <DISK_SIZE> | dd bs=64K of=/dev/sd"X"
```

However, `-bartpes` isn't in the `pv` [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pv), and it can't be a combination of switches either, since there's no separate `-a` switch. So what is it?

Comment: That's definitely the combination of several switches including [`-a, --average-rate`](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/quickref/pv.shtml)...

Comment: Ah, okay. I blame the crappy man page.

Comment: Well, blame the outdated man page on die.net, the package in Debian stable has the `-a` option listed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most command-line tools allow you to use a sort of "shorthand" for flipping multiple switches at once.  As you noted, `pv` has no `-bartpes` switch (and indeed, most tools for switches longer than one character use `--` to invoke them).

The following two commands are equivelant:

```
pv -bartpes

pv -b -a -r -t -p -e -s
```